# auto_open / workbook_open for other file, not this one

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I know that auto_open / workbook_open (latter = an event) runs when you open that file that contains it, in one of its modules.

I would like to put something in a module of file1.xlsm, that executes when any **other** file (.xls/ .xlsx/ .xlsm) is opened in Excel. If Excel and file1.xlsm are already open.

Does something like "sub any_other_workbook_open" exists? (just my humurous attempt at naming it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other workbook is opened by a procedure in file1.xslm this is very straightforward, and if not you can always punctually check the existence of any other workbook opened with this code:

```
Dim w as Object
Dim bOther as Boolean

For Each w in Application.Workbooks

   If w.Name<>ThisWorkbook.Name then bOther=True

Next w

If bOther=True then Call [Your Sub]
```

Well this is just one way and there are many others depending on what you aim to do !